# Create a new column based on condition applied from two other string columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have data in the below format :

```
pastLocation | currentLocation    
delhi        | bangalore          
delhi        | london,pune,delhi  
mumbai       | mumbai             
pune         | pune, noida
```

I have to create a new column named as `changeInLocation` where if `pastLocation` is present in `currentLocation` then value of new column would be `0` else `1`.
For example, in second row, `pastLocation` i.e. Delhi is present in corresponding `currentLocation` so value of `changeInLocation` should be `0`

Output should be in following format:

```
pastLocation | currentLocation   | changeInLocation
delhi        | bangalore         | 1
delhi        | london,pune,delhi | 0
mumbai       | mumbai            | 0
pune         | pune, noida       | 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `apply` with `in` for check membership and then cast to `int`:

```
df['changeInLocation'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['pastLocation'] not in x['currentLocation'], axis=1).astype(int)
```

Another solution iz zip columns and use `list comprehension`:

```
df['changeInLocation'] = [int(a not in b) for a, b in zip(df['pastLocation'], df['currentLocation'])]
```

---

```
print (df)
  pastLocation    currentLocation  changeInLocation
0        delhi          bangalore                 1
1        delhi  london,pune,delhi                 0
2       mumbai             mumbai                 0
3         pune        pune, noida                 0
```

Comment: Thanks Jez , I wonder when i will be able to write these codes by myself

Answer (score 2):

Similar to jezrael's solution, but taking care to remove whitespace and use `set` for performance:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'pastLocation': ['delhi', 'delhi', 'mumbai', 'pune'],
                   'currentLocation': ['bangalore', 'london,pune,delhi',
                                       'mumbai', 'pune, noida']})

sets = [{i.strip() for i in row} for row in df['currentLocation'].str.split(',').values]

df['changeInLocation'] = [int(past not in current) for past, current in \
                          zip(df['pastLocation'], sets)]

print(df)

     currentLocation pastLocation  changeInLocation
0          bangalore        delhi                 1
1  london,pune,delhi        delhi                 0
2             mumbai       mumbai                 0
3        pune, noida         pune                 0
```

Comment: Thanks jpp, it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Similar solution of jezrael(which is anyway more complete), but without casting:

```
df['changeInLocation']=df.apply(lambda x: 1 if x['pastLocation'] in x['currentLocation'] else 0, axis=1)
```

Comment: I would guess using a ternary statement instead of casting a Boolean array to int is hugely inefficient.